# Druid Postgresql syntax error while Initializing lookups on coordinator for first time

Tags: postgresql, druid

I am trying to setup lookups on a cluster-wide druid.

As mentioned in the doc- 
    http://druid.io/docs/latest/querying/lookups.html,
    1. Have included "druid-lookups-cached-global" in my load list.
    2. I tried to post an empty json object to initialize the configuration.

Command I ran:

```
curl -X 'POST' -d @blank.json http://localhost:8081/druid/coordinator/v1/lookups/config/
```

{localhost is my coordinator node in a distributed environment.My blank.json contains : {}}

This is the error I am getting while posting the blank json:

> org.skife.jdbi.v2.exceptions.UnableToExecuteStatementException:
>   org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near
>   "UPDATE"
>       Position: 18 [statement:"BEGIN;
>       LOCK TABLE druid_config IN SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE MODE;
>       WITH upsert AS (UPDATE druid_config SET payload=:value WHERE name=:key RETURNING *)
>       INSERT INTO druid_config (name, payload) SELECT :key, :value WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM upsert)
>       ;COMMIT;", located:"BEGIN;
>       LOCK TABLE druid_config IN SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE MODE;
>       WITH upsert AS (UPDATE druid_config SET payload=:value WHERE name=:key RETURNING *)
>       INSERT INTO druid_config (name, payload) SELECT :key, :value WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM upsert)
>       ;COMMIT;", rewritten:"BEGIN;
>       LOCK TABLE druid_config IN SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE MODE;
>       WITH upsert AS (UPDATE druid_config SET payload=? WHERE name=? RETURNING *)
>       INSERT INTO druid_config (name, payload) SELECT ?, ? WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM upsert)
>       ;COMMIT;", arguments:{ positional:{}, named:{value:[123, 125],key:'lookupsConfig'}, finder:[]}]

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The failure was due to postgresql version I was using. Upsert statements, which were getting fired from druid, are not supported in postgresql version lower than 9.1.

Comment: Postgres 9.1 has been [out of support](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) for over 2 years. You should really update to an up-to-date Postgres version. Postgres 10 is the current, with Postgres 11 being release this week. Since 9.5 there is `insert ... on conflict` available which is **much** more efficient than doing an upsert with a writeable CTE and is safe for concurrent execution.

Comment: I am not updating to 9.1. Was just specifying the reason for the problem i faced. Yes, i agree that 9.5 version has insert on conflict but druid should be able to support it as i am not directly connecting to Postgres here.